# Prime number calculator

Tags: ruby, primes

I am starting to learn Ruby.

This is pretty much the first thing I have coded. It's very simple; it's a prime number calculator. Since this is my first Ruby code, I would like some review on the following:

1. Adherence to Ruby standards
2. Is it done in the Ruby way (the way a Rubyist would have coded it)?
3. Adherence to Ruby naming conventions

What I am *not* looking for is a review on the prime number algorithm. I know there are more efficient ones out there.

---

File: `prime_numbers.rb`

```
class PrimeNumber
    def is_prime_kata(number)
        if number == 1 then return false end        

        max = Math.sqrt(number)

        (2..max).any? do |i| 
            if number % i == 0 then return false end
        end

        true
    end
end
```

---

File: `prime_numbers_test.rb`

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'set'
require_relative 'prime_numbers.rb'

class PrimeNumberTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_is_prime
        primeNumbers = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]

        primeNumber = PrimeNumber.new

        for i in primeNumbers
            result = primeNumber.is_prime_kata(i)
            assert_equal(true, result)
        end

        primeNumbersSet = Set.new(primeNumbers)
        allNumbersSet = Set.new(1..100) 

        nonPrimeNumbersSet = allNumbersSet - primeNumbersSet

        for i in nonPrimeNumbersSet
            result = primeNumber.is_prime_kata(i)
            assert_equal(false, result)
        end
    end 
end
```

Comment: first advice: 2-space indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor things. I will leave your actual questions to proper "Rubyists". :)

### defensive programming

I would change the first condition to

```
return false if number <= 1
```

0 is not a prime number, and negative numbers aren't either.
Maybe I would also adapt the test to check these cases.

### brevity

```
if <condition> then <statement> end
```

can be written

```
<statement> if <condition>
```

, so you could write

```
return false if number == 1
```

and

```
return false if number % i == 0
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the kind of input I was looking for.

Comment: I understand. But please note that I am just a beginner in Ruby as well. (Just an older beginner.)

Answer (score 3):

Aiming at your questions, your naming conventions are good. However, in your test you tend to switch between `camelCase` and `words_separated_by_underscores`. I would suggest sticking to one or the other (we tend to use underscores). Your algorithm looks good and taking ANeves suggestions will make it look more "Ruby"ish.

However, I am going to suggest a much more efficient way of generating your prime numbers and none prime numbers in your Test. Instead of typing each prime number between 1 and 100 by hand into an Array, you could use the [Array#Select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-select) method. It takes in an Enumerator, runs a given block against each item passed in, and returns an Array of only the items that return true.

```
prime_numbers = (1..100).select {|num| num.prime?}
```

This will given you the same Array you got by typing it all in manually. You can do the same for the none prime numbers.

```
non_prime_numbers = (1..100).select {|num| num unless num.prime?}
```

This'll return `num` only if it is not prime.

It'll save you a lot of typing and it will look more "Ruby"ish.

Answer (score 1):

Per your request, I suggest:

File: `prime_numbers.rb`

```
class PrimeNumbers
  def self.prime_kata? number
    n=number.floor
    return false if n < 2
    max=Math.sqrt(n).floor
    (2..max).none?{|k| 0==n % k}
  end
end
```

File: `prime_numbers_test.rb`

```
require 'mathn'
require 'test/unit'
require_relative 'prime_numbers'

class PrimeNumbersTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  LIMIT=100
  def test_is_prime_or_not
    primes=Prime.each(LIMIT).to_a
    non_primes = (0.. LIMIT).to_a - primes
    non_primes.each{|k| assert ! (PrimeNumbers.prime_kata? k)}
    primes.    each{|k| assert    PrimeNumbers.prime_kata? k }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write:

```
class PrimeNumber
  def is_prime_kata(number)
    return false if number == 1    
    max = Math.sqrt(number)    
    (2..max).all? { |x| number % x != 0 }
  end
end
```